# laravel (blade) and `:href="route(...)"`, `href="{{ route..)}}`, `:action="route(...)"`, and `action="{{route(...)}}`

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-blade

In Laravel's bootcamp (blade), there are two different syntaxes used for calling route() in a blade view component:

```
<x-dropdown-link :href="route('chirps.edit', $chirp)">
  {{ __('Edit') }}
</x-dropdown-link>
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('chirps.destroy', $chirp) }}">
  @csrf
  @method('delete')
<x-dropdown-link :href="route('chirps.destroy', $chirp)" onclick="event.preventDefault(); this.closest('form').submit();">
  {{ __('Delete') }}
</x-dropdown-link>
```

My understanding from documentation is that `{{ }}` is just a shortcut for `<?= ?>`
and by adding a `:` to html attribute laravel renders those attributes in the template.

So I started testing variations to see what works and doesn't work.  This is what I got:

1. `:href="{{ route(...) }}"` doesn't work
2. `href="{{ route(...) }}"` works
3. `:action="route(...)"` doesn't work
4. `action="{{ route(...)}}"` does work

So my understanding makes sense for 1, 2, and 4, but not 3:

What is going on here?  Does laravel not have an `:action` attribute for forms for some reason? or is it due to POSTing rather than GETting?  Or is my understanding of laravel's syntax flawed?

Comment: `:href` and `:action` look like they're maybe for `Vue` things? The correct syntax for standard HTML elements, like `<form>` and `<a>` would be `<form action="{{ ... }}">` and `<a href="{{ ... }}">`, replacing `...` with a PHP/Laravel function like `route()` or `url()`, etc.

Comment: I get that, thanks.  In laravel/blade documentation `:href` seems to be "short-attribute-syntax" (https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#short-attribute-syntax) for use in components.  Might be that the `<form>`, while in a component (`<x-slot>`), isn't actually a component (e.g. `<x-form>`) itself...?

Answer (score 0):

It seems putting the `:` before a laravel/blade component attribute is the way to pass a variable of that name/value into that component class' constructor ([passing-data-to-components](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#passing-data-to-components)).

So `:href` sets `__constructor($href)` to the string {{route(...)}} in the `<x-dropdown-links>` class, which laravel/blade constructs when the component is called.  Which explains why `<form :action...>` wouldn't work.

There is an `<x-form>` component in the extra [blade-ui](https://blade-ui-kit.com/docs/0.x/form) library, but interestingly even there it seems that the action attribute is set with `action=""` not `:action=""`.  So guessing there is an issue related to POSTing after all.